# How to measure number of operations performed in java

Tags: java

can i measure the number of operations the actually performed?
In my current project, I am trying to count the number of operation that performed written in Java. i thought about using counter per operation seems not realistically because there are a lot of conditions . Is there any  the number of operations the actually performed?

Comment: "Number of operations" is not a clearly defined thing.

Answer (score 0):

Using a counter would be your only solution.

```
if(condition){
    do something...
    counter++;
}
```

Copy and paste counter++ into appropriate blocks.